# Grappler optimization failed. Error: Op type not registered 'FusedBatchNormV3' in Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, tensorflow-serving

I am serving a model using Tensorflow Serving.

```
TensorFlow ModelServer: 1.13.0-rc1+dev.sha.fd92d2f
TensorFlow Library: 1.13.0-rc1
```

I sanity tested with load_model and predict(...) in notebook and it is making the expected predictions. The model is a ResNet50 with custom head (fine tuned).

If i try to submit the request as instructed in:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/serving/rest_simple

I got error

```
2022-02-10 22:22:09.120103: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/partitioned_function_ops.cc:197] Grappler optimization failed. Error: Op type not registered 'FusedBatchNormV3' in binary running on tensorflow-no-gpu-20191205-rec-eng. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
2022-02-10 22:22:09.137225: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1401] OP_REQUIRES failed at partitioned_function_ops.cc:118 : Not found: Op type not registered 'FusedBatchNormV3' in binary running on tensorflow-no-gpu-20191205-rec-eng. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

Any idea how to resolve? Will provide more details upon request.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what's wrong. the tensorflow server version seemed wrong. Just ensure it is:

TensorFlow ModelServer: 2.8.0-rc1+dev.sha.9400ef1

TensorFlow Library: 2.8.0